# Jinja Template dict/list filter "contains" or "like" - Saltstack

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I would like to filter on value that contain or start with 'foo_' and ignore other values in list.

values (**Can not be modified**):

```
TEST:
- foo_a
- foo_b
- bar_a
- bar_b
- test_c
```

Template :

```
{% for value in grains['TEST'] %}
- do something with value that contains "foo_"
{% endfor %}
```

How can i do it?

I tried with :

```
{% for value in grains['TEST']|map(^foo_) %}
- do something with value that contains "foo_"
{% endfor %}
```

=> No success

Comment: `{% for value in grains['TEST'] if  value.startswith('foo_') %} -do something {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each value is a string (which seems to be the case), you should be able to use the standard `startswith` method for strings, like `{% if value.startswith('foo_') %}`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do a substring search, you can check a variable for a string match like so. Make sure to make the variable into a string.

```
{% if '.mov' in var|string %}
   do something...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not recommended. Can you please explain your code so OP can understand and use it.

Comment: How did you determine this? This is the closest official documentation link I could find: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures